# Mathematica and Vector Representation of Planes

Tags: mathematica

If the vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ emanate from a point $A$, then its equation is

$\hspace{2in}$$x = A + su + tv$,

where $s, t \in \mathbb{R}$. I'm wondering how I can display these planes in Mathematica.

[image: ppp]

Thank you, Kaster (see below).

Comment: If you have a different question, please post a new question by using the Ask Question link to the top right of the page. Do not demolish an old answered question with a new one. This makes the existing answers nonsensical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is math.SE, not Mathematica.SE. But your question is simple enough so I can give you an answer

```
a1 = 1;
a2 = 2;
a3 = 3;
u1 = 1;
u2 = 2;
u3 = 3;
v1 = 4;
v2 = 5;
v3 = 6;
ParametricPlot3D[{a1 + s*u1 + t*v1, a2 + s*u2 + t*v2,a3 + s*u3 + t*v3}, {s, -10, 10}, {t, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "[t]his is math.SE not Mathematica.SE."

Comment: If by Mathematica you mean software, then there's whole stackexchange network for this kind of questions - [matematica.se](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com)

Comment: What is ".SE" though?

Comment: SE stands for Stackexchange. Have you followed the link I posted?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I glossed over it too quickly and didn't notice. Thank you.